# Changes made by one thread are not reflected in another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I have started learning threads in depth and while trying to understand the concepts I wrote the following code and I am not sure about the output of the code.Following is the code I wrote,

```
public class UnsafeCheck extends Thread {
    private static Person person;


    // This method is not thread safe without synchronization. Make the method 
    // synchronized to make the code thread safe.
    public synchronized Person getPerson() {
        if(person == null) {
            System.out.println("Inside if block");
            person = new Person("Kilarapu Yethendra", 27);
        }
        return person;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("thread's run method");
        getPerson();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UnsafeCheck uc = new UnsafeCheck();
        uc.start();

        UnsafeCheck uc1 = new UnsafeCheck();
        uc1.start();

        UnsafeCheck uc2 = new UnsafeCheck();
        uc2.start();        
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
thread's run method
Inside if block
thread's run method
Inside if block
thread's run method
Inside if block
```

If we observe the output changes made by the thread uc is not reflected in the thread uc1, which is why for each thread control is going to the if block.
I have expected person reference to be initialized when the uc1 executes the run method but person is still null for uc1 thread.

One more interesting observation I made was that if I make the getPerson() method as static I am getting the output as expected. Following is the output when getPerson() method is static.

Output:

```
thread's run method
Inside if block
thread's run method
thread's run method.
```

Kindly help me understand the flow.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the quick response. My doubt is clarified.

Comment: If there is an answer that gives the information you need, you can also choose to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring your method as

```
public synchronized Person getPerson()
```

means that it's synchronizing access using the containing `UnsafeCheck` instance (i.e. `this`) as the monitor. As you're creating three different `UnsafeCheck` instances, each of them will have their own lock and the code doesn't do what you expect it to do.

With

```
public static synchronized Person getPerson()
```

the monitor used is the same for all instances, i.e. `UnsafeCheck.class`, and you get correct synchronization for the `static` `Person` variable.

For more information about `synchronized` methods, have a look at Oracle's tutorial: [Synchronized Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I know what are You up to, the title is misleading. The synchronized keyword for a monitor locks it object-wise, so only one thread can enter the method PER Object.

You can do two things to have it application wide:

1.make getPerson method static (it will be synchronized application wide)

2.Use synchronized blocks that allow You to pick up synchronization objects (usually "this" for object-wise synchronization and "UnsafeCheck.class" for application wide)

Comment: How should `synchronize(this) { ... }` prevent other threads from initializing `person`?

Comment: @LuCio the thing You put into synchronize block round brackets only indicates on the Object that is used for checking if something is in the block. Hence every thread running Your method ON THE SAME object will have the same "this", so the synchronization is done object wide (same object can have it accessed only by one thread but other threads can access other objects of the same type) - the "this" value is unique to one object. Something.class is unique application wide.

Comment: But the OP uses three threads so how does this help to answer the question?

Comment: @LuCio hmm, number 1 answers the question, number two gives an answer how to do it with more control over it by using synchronized(UnsafeCheck.class)  block?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the quick response. My doubt is clarified